# How to call Array-valued Functions in fortran?

Tags: arrays, function, fortran

I want to write a function that returns an allocatable array in fortran

```
program test
    implicit none
    real a(3)
    real, allocatable :: F18(:)
    a = (/1,2,3/)
    print *, F18(a)
end program test

function F18(A)
implicit none
    real A(:)                   ! An assumed shape array
    real F18(size(A,1))         ! The function result itself is
                               ! the second dimension of A.  
    F18 =A                 !  
end function F18
```

It is expected to print "1 2 3" on the screen but I got an error:

> forrtl: severe (157): Program Exception - access violation

What's the problem?

Also, I have tried code like this:

```
program test
    implicit none
    real a(3)
    real, allocatable :: F18(:)
    a = (/1,2,3/)
    print *, F18(a,3)
end program test

function F18(A,n)
implicit none
    integer n
    real A(:)                   ! An assumed shape array
    real F18(size(A,1))         ! The function result itself is
                               ! the second dimension of A.  
    F18 =A                 !  
end function F18
```

During compiling I got:

```
Intel(R) Visual Fortran Intel(R) 64 Compiler XE for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 14.0.4.237 Build 20140805
Copyright (C) 1985-2014 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

D:\Fortran\Elephant.f90(6): error #6351: The number of subscripts is incorrect.   [F18]
    print *, F18(a,3)
-------------^
compilation aborted for D:\Fortran\Elephant.f90 (code 1)
```

I am really confused with fortran's function.

What is the right way to call Array-valued Functions in fortran?

@Fortranner

Comment: For rank 1 arrays, Fortran 2003 introduces the use of square brackets, `[]`, to delimit an array constructor.  So, `a = (/1,2,3/)` can be written `a = [1, 2, 3]`.  It's easier to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the properties of the function known to the caller.  The easiest way is to put it into a module and 'use' that module.  In your examples, in your main program you are declaring an array  'F18', which is not the function.

```
module mystuff

contains

function F18(A,n)
implicit none
    integer n
    real A(:)                   ! An assumed shape array
    real F18(size(A,1))         ! The function result itself is
                               ! the second dimension of A.
    F18 =A                 !
end function F18


end module mystuff

program test
    use mystuff
    implicit none
    real a(3)
    a = (/1,2,3/)
    print *, F18(a,3)
end program test
```

Comment: Thanks! :), one more small question, I can use F18((/1.,2.,3./),3), but if I defined `real A(:,:)` how can I pass the array argument directly?

Comment: You can use the intrinsic `reshape`: `F18( reshape([1,2,3,4], [2,2]) )`